# SQL Viewstate in Delphi ASP.Net - How to override PageStatePersister

Tags: asp.net, delphi, viewstate, delphi.net

I am following this example of storing the view state in the database. However, I have come to the end of the page and its asking me to override a property .. I have no idea how to achieve this in delphi. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I am using a Masterpage setup and .NET 2.0

[View State in DB](http://www.componentworkshop.com/blog/2009/06/27/advanced-net-storing-viewstate-in-a-database)

EDIT: For more information, this is what I have tried:

```
TDefault = class(System.Web.UI.Page)
   //Code excluded
public
   function GetPageStatePersister: PageStatePersister; 
   property PageStatePersister: PageStatePersister read GetPageStatePersister;
end;
```

But the code inside GetPageStatePersister isn't called.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this Delphi.NET, or Delphi Prism? Can you post the snippet of code that's causing the issue? It would be much easier to help with that information. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any code to post, I am trying to translate the code in the bottom of the link I posted into Delph.NET code ... I just don't know how ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to sort this out. Using .NET Reflecter I dug through the System.Web.UI.Page assembly and found that the function is called `get_PageStatePersiter` so I have just done:

```
function get_PageStatePersister: PageStatePersister; override;
```